# Summing 2 columns based on matching headers, contingent upon row criteria

Tags: excel

I have been attempting to setup a sumif function, but I'm absolutely stuck.

I was using this formula: `=SUMIF('Input results'!K$10:K$50000,"0",OFFSET('Input results'!K$10,0,'Input results'!$J$2,50000,1))`

J2 Formula

```
=ABS(MATCH($J10,$J$10:DA10,0)-MATCH($B$2,'Input results'!$J10:DA10,0))+2
```

but it only works if one date set, and i need it to be dynamic.

I need to have a cell sum the columns that correspond with the date in the headers, and only for rows in which are "PT" in columns J:U.  I have FT & PT setup to be 1,0 respectively.

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT5Rl.png "image"

Comment: image link not working, but try this: `=SUMIF('Input results'!K$10:J$50000,0,OFFSET('Input results'!K$10,0,'Input results'!$J$2,50000,1))`. Essentially, getting rids of the quotes around the `0`,

Comment: Try the image link now.  That formula works, but as i change the dates to month's in the future it doesn't offset by the correct amount of columns anymore.  I think my J2 formula may need adjusting, but I can't manage any tricks. Thanks,

Comment: =ABS((MATCH($J10,$J$10:DA10,0)-1)-MATCH($B$2,'Input results'!$V10:DA10,0))
I found it!  I changed the ranges on my J2, and netted out the first column with the "-1".  Thanks for looking!